# How to change color of pagination in bootstrap-vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I tried to change it with bootstrap examples but failed.

```
        <b-pagination
            v-model="currentPage"
            :total-rows="users.length"
            :per-page="perPage"
            align="fill"
            size='lg'
            first-number
            last-number
            class="my-0"
        ></b-pagination>
```

Comment: Coul you share what did you try ?

Comment: I tried to create custom css and include it in declaration.

Comment: [From here](https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate/issues/20)

Comment: Did you try the examples from there ? : https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination#customizing-appearance

Answer (score 5):

#### SCSS

As Troy pointed out in a comment, bootstrap has various SCSS variables you can use to customize the pagination. So if you're using SCSS this would be the preferred way.

[View the variables.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8fa0d3010112dca5dd6dd501173415856001ba8b/scss/_variables.scss#L782-L808)

#### CSS

You can add a class to `b-pagination` and use that class to target the `a` tags inside the pagination. Check the snippet for an example of this.

You can also use the following props (requires `v2.3.0+`) to place specific classes on the various types of buttons.
Note these will place the class on the `li`, so you'll still need CSS to target the `a` tag.
For more information about the class props check the [reference section](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination/#comp-ref-b-pagination-props)

```
page-class
first-class
last-class
prev-class
next-class
ellipsis-class
```

If you're using a `scoped` style tag in your components, note you might have to use a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) to target that `a` tags correctly.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.customPagination > li > a {
  color: red;
}

.customPagination > li.active > a,
.customPagination > li > a:hover
{
  color: white;
  background-color: green!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.4.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.4.1/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  <b-pagination
    :total-rows="50"
    :per-page="5"
    class="customPagination"
  >
  </b-pagination>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap-vue indeed is not so flexible when it comes to change to the default theme colors, but it is possible.

You first have to create a `custom.scss` file, where you can add new color themes to your bootstrap-vue.

On `src/assets/styles/custom.scss`:

```
// Override / set color variables
$myCustom: rgba(64, 206, 148, 1);
$primary: $myCustom;
```

Note that on the example above all bootstrap elements - including pagination - without a variant set, will get the `$myCustom` color.

Then you have to import this file and the original scss bootstrap file on your root vue component:

```
<style lang="scss">
 @import "./assets/styles/custom.scss";
 @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
</style>
```

On your code example, you pass the variant accordingly:

```
<b-pagination
    v-model="currentPage"
    :total-rows="users.length"
    :per-page="perPage"
    align="fill"
    size='lg'
    first-number
    last-number
    class="my-0"
    variant="primary"
></b-pagination>
```

In case you don't want to modify the default primary color, you can create a new variant on you `custom.scss`:

```
$theme-colors: ( "newVariant": rgba(0, 152, 152, 1));
```

Hope it suits you well

Comment: `b-pagination`doesn't have a `variant` prop from what i can see on the docs.

Comment: There are SCSS variables to control the color, background, and border of the pagination active page "button":  `$pagination-active-color`, `$pagination-active-bg`,  and `$pagination-active-border-color`. It is actually better to set the variables, than to provide override classes, as this does not increase your total compiled CSS size. See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/21041eecb7cb15cd9f5d4768d6c69d74c286f8e2/scss/_pagination.scss#L45-L50 For a compete list of Bootstrap v4.4 SCSS variables see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss